# How does the URL change without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript

[The URL on this page seems to change](http://gawker.com/man-commits-suicide-in-mall-after-girlfriend-refuses-to-1479660064) when I click in the comments section where it says "x More...".

How this this URL trickery happen?

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the HTML5 history api.